# Incorrect command error for composer network deploy

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html) on macOS.

```
$ composer -v
v0.20.1

$ composer network deploy -a dist/iot-perishable-network.bna -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f networkadmin.card


Incorrect command. Please see the list of commands above, or enter "composer network --help".
```

Available **composer network** commands in the list mentioned above: download, install, list, loglevel, ping, reset, start, upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Composer `v0.20.1`, the tutorial you are referring to is using Composer `v0.15.0`.

The `deploy` command has been removed since Hyperledger **0.19.0**.

See https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.0 :

> The following commands are no longer valid:
>
> ```
> composer runtime install
> composer network deploy
> composer network update
> composer network undeploy
> ```

You now have to use the following commands instead :

```
composer network install
composer network start
composer network upgrade
```

See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/commands for last valid commands.